# How do the booms on ISS (and other spacecraft) extend and retract?

Tags: iss, engineering, mechanisms

In an answer to my previous question, OrganicMarble posted a video:

The booms like through the center of ISS solar panels are quite common in space use - supporting magnetometers, keeping modules away from the core craft, etc.

I always thought they extend by "scisoring", pantograph mechanism action, whole boom getting slimmer but longer simultaneously. Apparently this is not the case - in the video you can see the still extended part of the boom remains "immutable", same unchanging structure. So what happens to the part of the boom that is being pulled into the assembly? Vanishing into a wormhole? Getting disassembled into atoms by nanomachines, to be reassembled later? How does that extending/retracting mechanism work?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

tl;dr - each bay of the mast collapses as it is pulled into the cylinder.

The ISS solar array mast is a truly ingenious mechanical structure which can be retracted into a remarkably small canister. It was developed by ATK and is called a Folding Articulated Square Truss (FAST) mast.

This picture shows a FAST mast without arrays.
[image]

The mast is composed of aluminum
longerons, stainless steel wire rope diagonals, aluminum rigid battens, and flexible fiberglass battens.

Every second batten ring is 
flexible.  Therefore,  the  battens  are  able  to  buckle  and  two  cells  of 
the  boom  can  be  collapsed.

[image]

The  deployment  is  driven  by  the  strain  energy  of  the  buckled  battens  and  is  controlled  by  a 
retaining 
mechanism in the container. This mechanism is a rotating nut
with four helical grooves. These helical grooves engage roller bearings located on
the corners of each mast section in a manner similar to that of a screw being pulled
through a rotating nut. It requires two revolutions of the nut to fully extend one mast
bay.

[image]

This image shows a cross section of the deployment mechanism. It's a bit complicated, but you can see the nut at the top (gray area), the collapsed truss sections at the bottom, and the drum/lanyard/cradle mechanism that feeds the sections into the bottom of the nut.

[image]

References

[ADVANCED DEPLOYABLE STRUCTURAL SYSTEMS FOR SMALL SATELLITES](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/20170003919.pdf)

[Static Stability of the Space Station Array Fastmast structure](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19960000328.pdf)

[Static Stability of a Three-dimensional Space Truss](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19950021309.pdf)

Personal Notes